# cronjob curl não funciona em aws

Tags: php, amazon-aws, cron

Olá, estou tentando gerar um cronjob no no Amazon Web Services (aws), tentei de diversas formas mas o mesmo não funciona. Aqui está o código:

> */2 * * * * /usr/bin/curl http://11.11.11.11/caminho/checar

usando apenas

> /usr/bin/curl http://11.11.11.11/caminho/checar

direto funciona normalmente, apenas a tarefa agendada que não. Alguém saberia me dizer qual é o problema? Obrigado!

Comment: Veja se o cron está rodando: `pgrep cron`

Comment: usei esse comando e me retornou isso: 21512
O cron esta lista nos processos em execução

Comment: OK, então veja também se o cron aparece nos logs: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Aparentemente não. Foi mostrado o seguinte erro: grep: /var/log/syslog: No such file or directory. Pode me dizer como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Qual distribuição linux está usando? Veja se algum dos arquivos existe: `/var/log/cron`, `/var/log/messages`

Comment: É o fedora. Esses arquivos existem, mas não tenho permissão para acessa-los

Comment: Nada resolvido ainda

Comment: Tentou `sudo grep -ic cron /var/log/cron` ?

Comment: Os erros mais comuns ao usar cron são: *permissões*, *sintaxe* errada no crontab e diferenças nas *variáveis de ambiente* (incluindo PATH, por isso sempre uso caminhos absolutos como você fez). No seu caso eu desconfio das permissões. Qual o caminho desse crontab e qual o usuário dono do arquivo? Você consegue executar o comando como esse usuário?

Comment: A seguinte mensagem foi exibida ao digitar o comando acima: 5814.

O servidor acessa ele mesmo com uma url de um arquivo, este arquivo possui essas atribuições:
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 ec2-user ec2-user 2774 Oct  6 12:33 checkAds.php`
Só as permissões do arquivo seria o suficiente?